# Aligning tooltip to relative parent

Tags: javascript, html, css

I spent last two days trying to fix this, but I realized that I cant do it alone. I'm trying to put my tooltip centered relative to parent. Here is my code =>

```js
let collection = document.querySelectorAll("[data-text]");
collection.forEach((ele, ind) => {
    var element = document.createElement("p");
    element.className = "tooltip-text";
    element.innerText = ele.dataset.text;
    element.dataset.name = "_" + ele.id + ind;
    document.getElementById(ele.id).appendChild(element);
         
    document.querySelector('#' + ele.id).addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
        document.querySelector('[data-name="' + element.dataset.name + '"]').style.visibility = 'visible';
     }, false);

   document.querySelector('#' + ele.id).addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
        document.querySelector('[data-name="' + element.dataset.name + '"]').style.visibility = 'hidden';
   }, false);

});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  background: #ccc;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 95vh;
}

.c-content{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.toprightcontrols {
  margin: 0 1.2% 0 0;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute; 
  justify-content: flex-end;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 150px;
  padding-top: 0;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.btnClass {
  padding: 10px;
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: right;
}

.btnClass:before {
  content: url('https://img001.prntscr.com/file/img001/nLMdieVITRSq82yZdqlWOw.png');
}

p.tooltip-text {
  color: black;
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: fit-content;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 2px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: white;
  pointer-events: none;
  padding: 6px 8px 20.2px 8px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  animation: fadein 0.2s ease-in;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

p.tooltip-text:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
  border: 8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
            <div id="c-content">
                <div class="toprightcontrols">
                    <span name="btn1" id="btn1" class="btnClass" data-text="Hello there"></span>
                    <span name="xxxxx" id="xxxxx" class="btnClass" data-text="Tooltip"></span>
                    <span name="something" id="something" class="btnClass" data-text="Click me"></span>
                    <span name="randomid" id="randomid" class="btnClass" data-text="I'm a text"></span>
               </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

The expected result must be something like this => 
[image]

Can you help me? I tried using  `float, text-align, justify-content, margin: 0 auto`, everything I saw to centralize but nothing works

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the element that needs to be the center reference as relative. In your case, you want to align to `.btnClass`. In that way, the class can wrap its content.

```css
.btnClass {
  position: relative;
}
```

After that you are able to center the tooltip. Define left position to `50%`, and use `transform` with `translateX(-50%)`, in that way the transform property moves -50% of the element itself, which is already 50% to the left, so the result is a perfect alignment.

```css
.tooltip-text {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Final Result:

```js
let collection = document.querySelectorAll("[data-text]");
collection.forEach((ele, ind) => {
var element = document.createElement("p");
element.className = "tooltip-text";
element.innerText = ele.dataset.text;
element.dataset.name = "_" + ele.id + ind;
document.getElementById(ele.id).appendChild(element);
         
    document.querySelector('#' + ele.id).addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
        document.querySelector('[data-name="' + element.dataset.name + '"]').style.visibility = 'visible';
     }, false);

   document.querySelector('#' + ele.id).addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
        document.querySelector('[data-name="' + element.dataset.name + '"]').style.visibility = 'hidden';
   }, false);

});
```

```css
.btnClass {
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip-text {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  background: #ccc;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 95vh;
}

.c-content{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.toprightcontrols {
  margin: 0 1.2% 0 0;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute; 
  justify-content: flex-end;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 150px;
  padding-top: 0;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.btnClass {
  padding: 10px;
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: right;
}

.btnClass:before {
  content: url('https://img001.prntscr.com/file/img001/nLMdieVITRSq82yZdqlWOw.png');
}

p.tooltip-text {
  color: black;
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: fit-content;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 2px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: white;
  pointer-events: none;
  padding: 6px 8px 20.2px 8px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  animation: fadein 0.2s ease-in;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

p.tooltip-text:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
  border: 8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
            <div id="c-content">
                <div class="toprightcontrols">
                    <span name="btn1" id="btn1" class="btnClass" data-text="Hello there"></span>
                    <span name="xxxxx" id="xxxxx" class="btnClass" data-text="Tooltip"></span>
                    <span name="something" id="something" class="btnClass" data-text="Click me"></span>
                    <span name="randomid" id="randomid" class="btnClass" data-text="I'm a text"></span>
               </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks that I found solution. I added:

```
.btnClass {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

to center every thing and then this:

```
p.tooltip-text {
  top:30px;
}
```

to offset it verticaly.

```js
let collection = document.querySelectorAll("[data-text]");
  collection.forEach((ele, ind) => {
  var element = document.createElement("p");
  element.className = "tooltip-text";
  element.innerText = ele.dataset.text;
  element.dataset.name = "_" + ele.id + ind;
                  document.getElementById(ele.id).appendChild(element);
         
 document.querySelector('#' + ele.id).addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
                document.querySelector('[data-name="' + element.dataset.name + '"]').style.visibility = 'visible';
            }, false);

            document.querySelector('#' + ele.id).addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
                document.querySelector('[data-name="' + element.dataset.name + '"]').style.visibility = 'hidden';
            }, false);

});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  background: #ccc;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 95vh;
}

.c-content{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.toprightcontrols {
  margin: 0 1.2% 0 0;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute; 
  justify-content: flex-end;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 150px;
  padding-top: 0;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.btnClass {
  padding: 10px;
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: right;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.btnClass:before {
  content: url('https://img001.prntscr.com/file/img001/nLMdieVITRSq82yZdqlWOw.png');
}

p.tooltip-text {
  color: black;
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: fit-content;
  position: absolute;
  top:30px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: white;
  pointer-events: none;
  padding: 6px 8px 20.2px 8px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  animation: fadein 0.2s ease-in;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

p.tooltip-text:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
  border: 8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
            <div id="c-content">
                <div class="toprightcontrols">
                    <span name="btn1" id="btn1" class="btnClass" data-text="Hello there"></span>
                    <span name="xxxxx" id="xxxxx" class="btnClass" data-text="Tooltip"></span>
                    <span name="something" id="something" class="btnClass" data-text="Click me"></span>
                    <span name="randomid" id="randomid" class="btnClass" data-text="I'm a text"></span>
                    </div>
         </div>
</div>
```